# QTextEdit and QTextDocument buffer problem?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I have a string. It has about 80000 line.I try to write

```
QTextDocument * textDocument=new QTextDocument();
textDocument->setHtml(list); //list is my string
txtEdit->setDocument(textDocument);
```

if string is not contain 80000 line, it can show records.But if has 80000 line, it can not show anything.

Do you have any solution about this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's a problem with the QString itself?  Did you tried to output the QString to the console (or called QString::size()) to make sure all the content is stored?

May be it's a limitation that comes from QTextEdit or QTextDocument and not QString.

Also, you could call [QString::capacity()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#capacity) to be sure of how much characters you can store in your QString :

```
int maximumNumberOfChars = list.capacity();
```